# Gradle: Controlling the order of runtimeClasspath property of a SourceSet

Tags: jar, gradle, build.gradle

I'm trying to learn how to control the order of the elements found in the `runtimeClasspath` property of my `SourceSet`.

The reason is that some JARs in my `SourceSet` contain methods that override methods found in other JARs, so I must make sure that the overriding JARs appear before the overridden JARs in the classpath.

Currently I'm achieving that by manipulating the `runtimeClasspath` `FileCollection` directly, but it's an ugly and fragile solution, especially because to do so I have to expicitely reference the different JARs by hardcoding their names and stuff like that.
I'd rather understand what determines the `runtimeClasspath` order, to see if I can act on that instead.

The [doc](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html%20doc) I read for `runtimeClasspath` property says "*The classpath to use when executing the classes of this source set.*".
In my `build.gradle` script I don't see any code that seems to affect the order within the `runtimeClasspath` collection, so I'm assuming that the `runtimeClasspath` order corresponds to the order of the elements in its `SourceSet`.

So I'm trying to understand what determines the order in the `SourceSet` itself.

The `SourceSet` is `test` and it's declared like this:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        ....
    }
    test {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/test/java'
        }
    }
}
```

I added this code to print the list of the files in the `runtimeClasspath`:

```
sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath.each {File file ->
    println file.name
}
```

and let's say that the `SourceSet` contains only 2 elements, so the output is:

```
thisShouldBeLast.jar
thisShouldBeFirst.jar
```

My problem is that I need the JAR in the second position to be in the first position instead.

Am I correct in assuming that the `runtimeClasspath` order corresponds to the order of the elements in its `SourceSet` ? And if yes, what determines that order ?

======================
ADDED EXAMPLE:

3 classes below. Each should go in a project on its own. So there will be 3 projects, each having only one class. Project "Runner" must have the other 2 as dependencies.
Then run the project "Runner" (from Eclipse or other IDE, or from command line after exporting the JARs, or in any other way) giving it a classpath containing the project "Original" and the project "Customized" and note the output. Then run it again but reverse the order of the 2 projects in its classpath and note the different output.

------------- Class that constitutes project "Original" : -------------

```
package testcp;

public class TestCP
{   
    public void show()
    {
        System.out.println("This is from the original JAR, not the customized one.");
    }
}
```

---

----------- Class that constitutes project "Customized" : -------------

```
package testcp;

public class TestCP
{   
    public void show()
    {
        System.out.println("This is from the customized JAR, not the original one.");
    }   
}
```

---

------------- Class that constitutes project "Runner" : ---------------

```
import testcp.TestCP;

public class Main
{   
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new TestCP().show();
    }
}
```

---

======================

Comment: Why don't You just exclude the conflicting dependencies instead of doing some nasty manipulations with classpath ordering?

Comment: That would be a problem because the issue is not purely about conflicting dependencies: `thisShouldBeFirst.jar` overrides only a few methods of `thisShouldBeLast.jar`, which also contains methods that are not overridden anywhere and are needed by the application. So the application wouldn't work if I exclude the whole `thisShouldBeLast.jar` .

Also, I thought that relying on the classpath order was not bad; I was regarding that more as a feature of Java whose use was considered good practice, but actually I'm getting more and more inputs suggesting that relying on the classpath order is bad.

Comment: So, although for the life of me I can't understand how can the classpath order be something developers shouldn't need to care about - especially considering the amount of third party JARs that typically come with any application and which might well have classes with the same qualified name - several sources seem to indicate that I might have to accept that idea before I understand it, and just figure out a way to change my design so that the classpath order becomes irrelevant.

Comment: Very interesting scenario to be honest. Can You provide any further details? Sample project? In general You just exclude the transitive dependencies and 'it works' but here it seems very complicated. In java/jvm world classpath is very important and the problem You have has a common name: **jar hell**. Every java developer was there at some time ;] What comes to me head is that You can also provide custom classloader and instead of *sorting* classpath You can fix the dependencies there. I'd rather avoid that solution as well.

Comment: Well, "jar hell" is quite spot-on, sounds like the younger brother of the good old "DLL hell" in Windows... I had hoped that those days were gone but nope, unless I'm missing something big here, which might well be the case.
I'll be glad to post a sample project here as soon as possible; I'm very interested in understanding this general subject.

Comment: Just to quickly summarize, the project uses a 3rd party open source JAR, which I had to slightly customize so I created another JAR having some classes with the same qualified name as the classes I wanted to customize from the 3rd party JAR (I previously used the word "override" but I realized that's ambiguous because my issue has not to do with overriding methods in subclasses).
So I definitely need my new JAR to come before the original 3rd party JAR in my classpath, otherwise the classes from the original JAR will be used instead of the ones in my new JAR.

Comment: Ok, waiting for the sample project.

Comment: @Opal and anyone else, I added the sample projects at the bottom of the question. Since the problem is very basic, so is the sample, which is merely meant to avoid misunderstandings about what kind of situation I'm talking about.

Comment: You can also set the order by dependencies only. http://stackoverflow.com/a/38743046/715269